# stability assessment

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I have been asked to assess the stability of my numerical solutions to two different sets of transient differential equations that govern the same phenomena. I am not sure how I can assess and compare the stability of the two solutions.

I am solving the equations using the same Matlab ode solves and discretising the equations in space using similar schemes. I am confused on whether stability is analysed by looking at the solution or the methods used to get to the solution. I would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I just googled what closed form solutions refer to. I am not sure if I understood correctly but I am guessing in case of ODE's, exact solutions would be regarded as closed form solutions. I know that my equations, if linearised and simplified return the linear wave equations to which exact solutions exist.

Comment: the linearised system is basically the linearised wave equation: d^2p/dx^2 = C* d^2p/dt^2